# Controlling RichTextBox position with other ScrollBar

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, richtextbox, splitcontainer

I have richTextBox (dock style = fill, scrollbar = only vertical, wordwrap = false) in splitcontainer.panel1

```
splitcontainer.panel1.Controls.Add(richTextBox);
```

In case when richTextBox needs to be scrolled (when its width is bigger than width of splitcontainer.panel1).

I wish a scrollbar would appear (but in splitcontainer.panel1, not scroll bar from richTextBox).

Is it possible to handle?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly doesn't make sense to do that.  For the sub-panel's scrollbars to even work properly, you couldn't dock-fill the RichTextBox control.  Then you would have to constantly resize the RichTextBox control based on the TextChanged event, and that could get messy.

It's also not clear *why* you couldn't just set the ScrollBars to both:

```
richTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both;
```

It would seem to do the job you really want it to do.